# How to check the percentile of each row based on a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a dataset with a `id` column for each event and a `value` column (among other columns) in a dataframe. What I want to do is categorize each `id` based on whether it is on the 90th percentile, 50th percentile, 25th percentile etc. of the frequency distribution of the value colum.

Example,

```
id      value
1       12.5
2       4.6
....
```

So, I'd add another column `category` to it depending upon the what percentile of the value column it falls in. How do I do that?

Comment: Was my answer not what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `quantile` method. For instance, assigning to `0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75` quantiles could be done this way:

```
df['quantile'] = 0.0

for q in [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]:
    df.loc[df['value'] >= df['value'].quantile(q), 'quantile'] = q
```